# Is it possible to wrap an exception in project reactor stream

Tags: project-reactor

[image]

For example above. `map1` is a convert function, but exception will be thrown if input is D2. I want the exception would be wrapped and returned a result in `map2` function.

```java
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 0, 4).cache();
        flux.map(i -> 2/i)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.just(9))
                .map(i -> i * 2)
//                .doOnError(e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage()))
//                .onErrorContinue((e, i) -> System.out.println(i))
                .map(i -> i + "here1")
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The code example is above. The output is

```
4here1
18here1
```

But I want

```
4here1
18here1
0here1
```